# Question about "FUDing" with hex editor

Tags: malware

I see a lot of materials in Internet about this technique. I'm not really interested in malwares, but I'm curious when you change bytes to an exe with other bytes, wouldn't this corrupt the exe? I can give example videos if somebody didn't understand my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to load into tool such as OllyDbg and you'll have instructions and you can modify them to do the same sort of job as alternative instructions then save them to executable so byte signature against your file would be bypassed.

You can rewrite code to do same job. Let's make a really basic scenario.
Imagine you seen in executable. I'm going to pretend this is x86 executable:

```
004CFF64 - B8 05000000           - mov eax,00000005
004CFF69 - B8 07000000           - mov eax,00000007
```

So, 10 byte in total.

You could rewrite that as:

```
004CFF64 - B8 05000000           - mov eax,00000007
004CFF69 - 90                    - nop 
004CFF6A - 90                    - nop 
004CFF6B - 90                    - nop 
004CFF6C - 90                    - nop 
004CFF6D - 90                    - nop
```

Which is still 10 bytes in total but the signature has now changed.
Reason why we used a NOP (No Instruction Preformed) is because it does nothing but use space.

Now, in real world situation you won't come across it as easy as that you'll have to use code-caves and so on. For example let's say you needed to write more than 10 bytes of code then you really can't do it since you would overwrite next instruction which would corrupt the executable. Well, what you do is use `JMP` instruction to free space in memory which then you'll do all code there and you'll use `JMP` to get back to normal execution of code.

Byte signatures are generally do on whole file and static parts of the executable.
For example .text (Sometimes known as .code etc) which is the executable part of the code and the memory regions are not writeable so they won't change although you can override the permissions with `VirtualProtect` API.

I could go into much more detail about obfuscation, how byte signatures works and so on but I hope that answers your question if not leave a comment and I'll expand my answer.

Comment: I understand it only from the first part(before the example). Thank you, great answer

Answer (score 0):

It *could* easily corrupt an exe but there is a lot of data in an exe that isn't actually executable. Also much that may be rarely executed and so might be changed without discovery for a long time.

There are tools that can help with this kind of exercise without changing the actual code. They look for the "resources" defined in the executable. Typically strings containing descriptions, fixed data, that kind of thing. "Resource Hacker" is one such tool.